# pointer to address using another pointer C

Tags: c

I've got a function which receives a pointer to a string.
Now I want to duplicate this pointer, so I could run on the string with one pointer, and have another pointer which saves the beginning of the string. I hope my question is clear, I don't want to create a pointer to the pointer (which points to where the first pointer points and changes with it), I want a pointer which will point to the address of which the first pointer points.

I tried many different ways but none of them worked, this is my latest try, I keep getting
"initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"

```
int move_chars (char *str, int start, int end, int dist){
    int strsize = end - start + 1;
    char *p =  *str;
```

Comment: `char *p = str;` as `str` is a `char*` and `*str` is a `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
char *p =  str;
```

to declare a pointer to a char and initialise it with the value of another char pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer cant belive that I didnt try this! If I want to move the pointer forward should I use p++ or *p++? cant seem to find the diference//

Comment: Use `p++` to move the pointer forward.  `*p++` could be used to combine assignment and pointer increment, often in a loop.  e.g. `while(*src != '\0') *dest++ = *src++;` as a `strcpy` implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Since `p` is of type `char *` and `str` is also of type `char *`, you just need to do:

```
char *p = str;
```

To make `p` point to the same memory location as `str`.

Your code:

```
char *p = *str;
```

Attempts to copy into `p` the value of the first `char` at the memory location that `str` points to, and since `p` is expecting another memory location and not a `char`, you get an error.

Your error says that "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast". This is telling you what's happening: The compiler thinks you are manually pointing `p` to a specific memory location, using the value of the `char` `*str` returns as an integer. This is technically doable, but you are required to manually cast the integer into a pointer, just  so it's clear you're doing what you intended, and it's not a bug like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *p = str
```

This will declare a pointer to character and makes **p** point to the memory location where **str** points

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but why when try to do *str=p rihgt after your suggested answer I get an error again?

Comment: @user1108310: what are you doing? it should be char *p = str;

Comment: first I do char *p =str, than p++ ,and now I want to bring str to where p points, so Im supposed to do *str=p right? but that doesnt work